# REST Api integration - how to force payment page's language?

Tags: api, paypal, integration

I integrated PayPal API and have the problem that Payment page are always displayed in Polish (which is my native language), but not English. I'd like to force payment pages to display always in English because my whole site is in English. How can I do that? There is no setting in my merchant's account for that :/

I know that there are some hacks to force language, but they works only for PayPal's buttons, not API interfaces :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Paypal REST api - How to control the display language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23524011/paypal-rest-api-how-to-control-the-display-language)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the locale/language and input settings on your browser.  The locale affects which language etc is presented to visitors of PayPal.

However if you want to force the locale, there are a couple of ways to do so (depending on the product you are using):

WP: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPCustomizing/#id0864A0Q60Y4

EC: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECButtonIntegration/#id089TGK09030